# why wont my latest commit on github pass checks for github pages?

Tags: github, github-pages, git-commit

[my github commits](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIimv.png)

If you look at the image, an old commit is currently in use for the github pages, why and what do I have to do to make the latest commit pass checks?
I have been told to try vigilant mode but I don't think thats what the issue is about as all the commits are verified.

Answer (score 0):

I simply took down the github pages for the repo and republished and it checked the latest commit.